# Getting pixel value of css style through Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the exact pixel value of a margin-left style applied to a div element with the calc() function, I need this value sent to a function in my typescript, so far my code for this looks as follows

HTML:

```
<div id="cont" class="container" [style.width.px]="getWidth()" 
  [ngStyle]="getOffset([style.margin-left])">
```

TypeScript:

```
getOffset(marg){
    var style;
    if(marg > 130){
        style = {'margin-left': 'calc(50% -'+String(this.offsets[this.arrPosWidth])+'px)' };
    }else{
        style = {'margin-left': '130px' };
}

return style
```

}

Sending the style through that function was a long shot and I've tried accessing the margin-left style with element.style but this just returns a literal string with calc(50%-..px).  Is there any way for me to get the value in pixels for the margin-left style applied to that particular element?

Comment: You want to calculate the new left margin based on the current left margin? That will probably cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I just want to prevent the margin-left of that element going below 130px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through the `ngAfterContentInit` Lifecycle hook.

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbfp8x

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // this is what we initially set the margin to
  public margin:number = 75;

  // Bound to your element
  @ViewChild('myElem') element: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // get the current margin and then strip off the 'px'
    let currentMargin:number = parseInt((this.element.nativeElement.style.marginLeft as string).substring(0,2));

    // add any restriction logic you need.
    if(currentMargin > 25){
      this.margin = 25;
    }
  }
}
```